# Javascript Regex Whitespace Replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the value of an `<select></select>` tag as set from the selected `<option>` value and replace any whitespace in the value with a dash. at the moment I am just then `console.log()` the value for testing but for some reason instead of selecting whitespace it is selecting and replacing lower case "s". The code I am using is: 
`<select onchange='var cat = this.value; var modi = cat.replace(/\s/g , "-"); console.log(modi);'>`

Example:
*for example assume the this.value is equal to "test value"*

Output: te-t value
Expected Output: test-value

Comment: Tip for asking questions like this: Do not ask for regular expressions. You need to do some kind of text manipulation which might better be served by other means. Consider rephrasing the question to "How can I replace whitespace in an HTML option element?"

Comment: Thanks @RayToal that's a good point, it was more to see if I missed something in my regex, I got so blinded by the frustration of reading the same thing over and over again saying it should work, that I forgot to look at alternative.

Comment: The code in your question [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/bxqabgc9/1/) (in Chrome, anyway). Given that you say the literal "s" was replaced I'm wondering if this is because of the way some browsers parse the string that is the `onchange` attribute - which browser were you testing with?

Comment: Tip number 2: Avoid placing JavaScript in HTML strings because it made your regex parse funny. So I guess this was a kind of regex question after all! :-)

Comment: @nnnnnn Nice fiddle, yes it does work in Chrome, interesting.....

Comment: @nnnnnn I was testing in the latest version of chrome, interesting... now I wonder what could have been causing it! Maybe it could be the fact that the value field of the select is being dynamically generated in a loop by a CMS (silverstripe to be exact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
cat.split(" ").join("-");
```

Comment: Why would this work if `cat.replace(/\s/g , "-");` doesn't work?

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you, I don't know why I didnt think of this, I just got so far down the Regex rabbit hole I forgot about some basic javascript I have used before! I am wondering why this works and the regex doesn't however.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "test value";
str = str.replace(/ /g,"-");
alert(str);
```

Comment: Because there is no pattern find in /\s/g while finding

Comment: Yes. Good one. I miss something.

Comment: @nnnnnn In the question, the OP has placed all of the JavaScript inside HTML as an attribute string. Perhaps the `\s` in the attribute string was first translated to a plain old `s` (escaping within the string before parsing the regex). That would explain the actual output, where the `s` in test was replaced.

Comment: @RayToal - Yes, that was my suspicion, though it seems to work for me as is in Chrome. But if that is the case the answer should mention it rather than proposing something slightly different with no explanation, because from a pure regex perspective it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
var reg = new RegExp(" ","g");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
        var str = "Is this all there is?";
        var patt1 = / /g;
        var result = str.replace(patt1,"-");            
    }
```